# How to list text files in a directory in Progress 4GL?

Tags: progress-4gl

I have a folder in c drive,whicn contain 1000 txt file,i want
 to get the list of all these txt file. How can i get this list?

Answer (score 10):

Use the `OS-DIR()` function.

For example:

```
DEFINE STREAM dirlist.
DEFINE VARIABLE filename AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(30)" NO-UNDO.

INPUT STREAM dirlist FROM OS-DIR(".").

REPEAT:   
    IMPORT STREAM dirlist filename.
    DISPLAY filename.
END.

INPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

For example: ipcPath = "C:\temp\

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER ipcPath  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE chFiles        AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

INPUT FROM OS-DIR(ipcPath).
REPEAT:
    IMPORT UNFORMATTED chImport NO-ERROR.
    DISPLAY chFiles FORMAT "X(75)".
END.
INPUT CLOSE.
```

chFiles is a spacedelimeted list and contains the filename, the path, and an 'F' or 'D' tag.

Comment: very similar to Dave Webb's Answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a directory-tools program which enable a developer to do  all kinds of fun things with file systems. You can get the code here: http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-16578